# Leaflet error when trying to edit a polygon

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am trying to edit a polygon created using leaflet-draw.
However, I receive the following error every time that I try to edit the polygon. (I dont see those draggable points on the polygon which can be used to resize it)

> leaflet.js:formatted:854 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'lat' of null(…)

[image]

If I try to save the polygon without making changes I get the following error

> leaflet.draw.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispose'
>   of undefined(…)

[image]

This is my leaflet edit toolbar code -

```
        var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
        map.addLayer(drawnItems);
        var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
            draw: {
                position: 'topleft',
                polygon: {
                   allowIntersection: false,
                    drawError: {
                        color: '#b00b00',
                        timeout: 1000
                    },
                    showArea: true
                },
                circle: false,
                polyline: false,
                rectangle: true,
                marker: false,
            },
            edit: {
                edit:true,
                featureGroup: drawnItems
            }
        });
        map.addControl(drawControl);
```

Please help!

Comment: Which versions of Leaflet and Leaflet.draw are you using?

Comment: @ghybs I am facing a new issue. I've posted a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40337606/leaflet-edit-toolbar-icons-misaligned . Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I updated leaflet, leaflet-draw and angular packages to the latest version and that fixed the problem.