# Leaflet edit toolbar icons misaligned

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am using -

Leaflet version 1.0.1
and Leaflet draw version - 0.4.1

The edit toolbar icons appear to be misaligned on page load.
Please help!

[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue: http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/qavu/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue by using the css file in the "Master" branch together with the leaflet-draw script which I downloaded.